# Linux Mint 12 claims to come with Gnome 3 but gnome-about says it is Gnome 2

Tags: gnome, linux-mint, gnome3

Can anyone help me explain this?

[image]
Just installed a fresh copy of Linux Mint 12 downloaded from their website only a few days ago. They claim that it uses Gnome 3 but gnome-about says it is Gnome 2.

Answer (score 1):

It is Gnome 3, your above screenshot shows the version of the application explaining gnome not Gnome itself.

Try in terminal

```
gnome-shell --version
```

or open *System Monitor* and post what you see in system tab.